# Grouping by with a map key

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, dictionary, group-by, hql

I want to sum the values of a map grouping the result by its keys. I have the following query.

```
SELECT b.foreignEntity.id, KEY(b.map), sum(VALUE(b.map))
  FROM B b GROUP BY b.foreignEntity, KEY(b.map)
```

Unfortunately the execution of it ends up with the following runtime exception.

```
Column ?map1_.map_key? must appear in the group by clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

I tried changing the query to the following one by adding `AS` but it looks like `HQL` does not understand, what I want.

```
SELECT b.foreignEntity.id, KEY(b.map) AS group1, sum(VALUE(b.map))
  FROM B b GROUP BY b.foreignEntity, group1
```

The exception I get in this case is

```
Column ?scoretype? does not exist.
```

How do I achieve what I want with `HQL`? The underlying database is PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange, but joining the entity with the map attribute solved the problem.

```
SELECT b.foreignEntity.id, KEY(m), sum(VALUE(m))
  FROM B b JOIN b.map m GROUP BY b.foreignEntity, KEY(m)
```